# Reload UIAlertController data

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have created an action where I load random data from JSON in an `UIAlertController`, I want `action2` to reload the data so that another random fact is shown in the message. This is my code:

```
@IBAction func Aleatorio(sender: AnyObject) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/json/get_azar.php?id=\(Int(arc4random_uniform(500) + 1))").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

        if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["azar"].array {

           let azar = resData[0]["descripcion"].string!



    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "¿Sabías que...?", message: "\(azar)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cerrar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Otro Dato", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in


            }

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.33, green:0.0, blue:0.34, alpha:1.0)

    alert.addAction(action1)
    alert.addAction(action2)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the alert controller that has already been displayed.  In fact, tapping the action button will dismiss the alert controller.

You need to present a new alert controller in action2. Essentially, just call self.Aleatorio(sender) in action2.

```
let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Otro Dato", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in
    self.Aleatorio(sender)
}
```

This code isn't particularly efficient as it goes to the network each time, which may introduce delays.  It would probably be better to fetch a number of facts from your data base initially and then select one of those randomly each time.

Also, by convention, method names and variables start with a lower-case letter, so the function should be `aleatorio`

Comment: Thanks!! It worked perfectly, I will keep the last fact in mind.